# Ocultar pasta do URL

Tags: htaccess

Galera estou com dificuldade de adapta esse codigo, o meu site esta em uma pasta chama site quero ocultar essa pasta e deixa tudo se tivesse na raiz, ate ai funciona, o problema esta quando vou acessar a pasta 'admin' quando me logo da erro 404, será que alguem pode me ajudar

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!site/)(.*)$ site/$1?url_rewrite [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\.html$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2&section=$3&ss=$4&url_rewrite [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\.html$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2&section=$3&url_rewrite [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\.html$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2&url_rewrite [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)?(\/)$ index.php?module=$1&url_rewrite [QSA,L]

php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 32M
```

Comment: tem um monte de pergunta parecida com a sua, dê uma espiada se não tem alguma resposta que ajude nelas: [Tag htaccess](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htaccess) e [URL Amigável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+amigável+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Método A

Se queres evitar que o 'esqueleto' da pasta `site` seja exibido ao acessar a pasta diretamente pelo URL (`meusite.com/site`), como neste exemplo abaixo:

> ```
> /site
>     • imagens
>     • js
>     • css
>        • meusEstilos.css
> ```

basta adicionares dentro dessa pasta um ficheiro `index.html` ou um ficheiro `index.php` e adicionar um conteúdo *dummy* nesse ficheiro. Por exemplo:

**index.html**

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <h3>Nothing to see here</h3>
</body>
```

---

### Método B

Se quiseres optar por usar `htaccess` em vez disso para redirecionar o tráfego destinado à pasta `site` para uma página 404 por exemplo, podes fazê-lo assim:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/site/.*$
```

ou então

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/site/ http://www.meusite.com/?
```

se quiseres redirecionar o tráfego para a *homepage* ou para uma página especifica.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, mais infelizmente acho não consegui me expressar. tenho o seguinte site http://pingimoveis.com.br ele tem o front que esta dentro da pasta site, já conseguir ocultar essa pasta da url com o código que postei porem quando eu me logo pingimoveis.com.br/admin (apos o login) ele de redireciona para pagina de erro.